# Cannot access Symfony app on Homestead VM

Tags: symfony, vagrant, homestead

I have been trying to get a Symfony app to run on Homestead. Each time I try to load the site `http://homestead.app` my browser says "This site can’t be reached". I am not sure why this is happening. The process I followed was:

**Create a Symfony application on my Linux mint host system:**

- `mkdir ~/dev/sites/symfony`
- `cd ~/dev/sites/symfony`
- `symfony new my_project`. This creates Symfony application in: "~/dev/sites/symfony/my_project"
- `composer require --dev laravel/homestead`
- `php vendor/bin/homestead make`
- Edit Homestead config file `vim Homestead.yaml`
- `vagrant up`

"Homestead.yaml" file contains:

```
ip: 192.168.10.10
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    -
        map: ~/dev/sites/symfony
        to: /home/vagrant/Code
sites:
    -
        map: homestead.app
        to: /home/vagrant/Code/my_project/web
        type: symfony
databases:
    - homestead
name: symfony
hostname: symfony
```

When I try to access the site through Chrome browser I get a 'The site can't be reached'. I checked the nginx config, but looks ok to me:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name homestead.app;
    root "/home/vagrant/Code/my_project/web";

    index index.html index.htm index.php app_dev.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app_dev.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/homestead.app-ssl-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    # DEV
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|app_test|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/homestead.app.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/homestead.app.key;
}
```

If I try to ping the site from host system `ping homestead.app` it is translating the address to `192.168.10.10` but fails to return a ping response. This indicated that the URL is being correctly mapped to the IP address.

I checked the '/etc/hosts' config for both host and guest systems. On the host system there is an entry for `homestead.app` which maps to `192.168.10.10`. I noticed that in the guest system the hosts file only mapped `homestead` instead of 'homestead.app'. I updated the hosts file to include both. However, that didn't make any difference.

Comment: What is returning `ping 192.168.10.10` ?
Are you sure there is no error in your `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Did you add your app to your hosts file?  Like `homestead.app 127.0.0.1` ? Did you do `vagrant up`?  Did it show you what host it's using?  For me it always requires me to go to port 8000 which is forwarded, so in your case, `homestead.app:8000`

Comment: @JasonRoman I tried using port 8000 but it made no difference. The guest system is up and running (i.e. `vagrant up`). The nginx config in the question is from the guest system.

Comment: @Benjen try to look at logs file and verify files permission

Comment: @عارفبنالأزرق I looked at this page on file permissions: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html. Still no luck. I can confirm that the project files on guest belong to `vagrant` user and that nginx is also running as `vagrant` user, which according to the documentation should be the same.

Comment: @Benjen have you looked to logs file?

Comment: Out of interest, I have since tried to set up Laravel instead of Symfony on Homestead. Also experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @عارفبنالأزرق nginx access and error log files on guest are empty. Based on this I am guessing that the request is not even getting through to the nginx server